# jQuery, how would i create a random name pulled from a name-list.txt based on user input

Tags: jquery, string, cordova, random

I am building a phone app using phonegap build so I am limited to HTML5, CSS and javascript / jQuery, but i would like to achieve the following.

I would like to take input from the user which could be "John Smith" and then based upon that input, pull certain lines from the file, so if another user enters the same name, they will get the same result. I googled and found some articles for using syllables and character count from the name to generate a name etc but nothing really seemed to do what I wanted to do.

I also planned on hashing the users input and then storing it in a remote db with a randomly generated name and then if the hash comes up again it would use the same name, but something local on the device would be great to help with load times etc.

Do you have any idea what would be the best way to generate a random name based off the users input? Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

My name-list.txt looks like this:

```
cup
annihilator
bobby
val
halen
chupa'clark'bra
hawii
mushinator
release
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not save it as javascript object instead of text?

Then you can make a quick ajax call and get the object. This is also much faster than using plain file and running an regex.

Depending on how contents of your  file are, I can help you construct that JSON.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. At best it's a comment.

Comment: Updated!.. The question is ambiguous. If he can share his input file I can give a more precise answer. I would consider this edit as an answer though.

Comment: Atif i appreciate the help but the data storage isn't the issue at the moment, im more after an algorithm to calculate a name based on user input.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own function for this, its kind of ghetto but it does the job. Hopefully this is of use to someone else :P

```
function generateName(name) {
        if(name != null) {
            // prepare the variables
            var sum = 0;
            var total = 0;
            var points = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26];

            // get the string
            var string = name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "");
            if(string.length > 50) {
                string = string.substring(0,50);
            }

            // tally up the points of the letters
            for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++ ) {
                var letter = string.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
                var letterIndex = letter.charCodeAt(0) - 65;
                sum += points[letterIndex];
            }

            // make the number bigger
            if(sum % 2 === 0) {
                if(sum < 100) {
                    total = parseInt(Math.pow(sum, (sum)));
                }
                else 
                {
                    total = parseInt(Math.pow(sum, (sum / 100)));
                }
                console.log("it was even" + total);
            }
            else {
                for(var i = 0; i < (sum*sum); i++) {
                    parseInt(total = total + sum);
                }
            }
            total = total + string.length;

            // check if the value is in a valid range, if not, loop again
            var word1 = total;
                while(word1 > 25000) {
                word1 = parseInt(word1 / 2);
            }

            var word2 = parseInt(word1.toString().split("").reverse().join(""))+string.length;

            while(word2 > 25000) {
                word2 = parseInt(word2 / 2);
            }
        }
        else {
            var word1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*25000)+1);
            var word2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*25000)+1);
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "names.txt",
        }).done(function(msg) {
            var names = msg.split('\n');
            var name1 = names[word1].toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) { return letter.toUpperCase(); });
            var name2 = names[word2].toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) { return letter.toUpperCase(); });

            $("#name-space").hide();
            $("#name-space").html("<div id=\"name-wrapper\">Your name is:<br /><h1>" + name1 + " " + name2 + "</h1></div>");
            $("#name-space").fadeIn(100);
        });
    }
```